# Why did my comment get removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

I left a comment answering another comment on 
[Eraser: "Warning: This computer has had System Restore or Volume Shadow Copies enabled.". Does my USB flash drive contain any copies of files stored?](https://superuser.com/q/1192948/116475). I see that both comments have been removed. Why? We were discussing about answers to the question.

I don't have a copy of the two comments so I'll leave a mod to take care of quoting the comments.

Comment: You are not meant to have discussions in the comment section.  Once you determined, you didn't actually have an issue, I deleted my comments and flagged your comments as being obsolete.  I attempt to flag comments, once we go from trying to clarify something, to have an actual discussions.

Comment: @Ramhound my comment was only a one-line sentence (it answered your comment) and I don't think it qualified as a discussion. Removing your comment as you did may cause future readers to leave the same comment as the one you wrote. Then I'll have to write my comment again. My comment was also answering the 3 close votes.

Comment: I won't argue about the reasons I deleted my comment.  I flagged everything, cleaned up my own comments, in order to clean up the comment section.  If you feel somebody will have the same question, clarify the question, so that can't possibly happen.  Your response to my comment should have been intergrated into your question anyways.  *Comments should NEVER exist forever, they are meant, to be deleted evenetually.*

Comment: @Ramhound from what I recall we only had 1 comment each. Can you check your flag history?

Comment: I did not flag your comment.  I will again repeat for your growth as a Superuser member, comments are not meant to exist forever, if I had already fixed the comment then your comment saying I had modified my comment isn't required.  *I have not flagged a single comment, at meta.superuser.com, in over 5 months.*

Comment: @Ramhound "comments are not meant to exist forever" they should be left   at least until the close votes expire, in case they address close votes.

Comment: @Ramhound "for your growth as a Superuser member" we have written pretty much the same amount of posts (questions + answers) and both of us joined the site around five years ago (you joined a few months before me).

Comment: I am trying to encourage you not focus on if your comments are deleted.

Comment: Frank, if a user wants their comments gone then that is up to them. If you want to address what was mentioned *in a comment* then that is up to you. You can even edit your question to do so if you like. Comments are transitory and subject to deletion, if there's anything you want kept in them then it's up to you to do something with it. *I* deleted your earlier comment because it was crossing the line. [Be nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Mokubai Why was it crossing the line?

Comment: Because rather than discussing the matter constructively your comment was appealing to the peanut gallery with "(hey look what user x has done)". That comment was targeted to elicit a response and, in short, was not nice.

Comment: Additionally, you say we have the same amount of questions and answers (we actually don't considering I have asked 3 questions in nearly 6 years), as if asking a ton of questions teach you how the community works.  I am not saying I am perfect, far from it, but I like to think I got a pretty good idea how the community functions

Comment: (I believe you learn more more about the community and how it functions from answering questions then asking them) but that's just me personally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment you replied to was deleted by its owner, as is their right to do.  Your comment was then flagged as obsolete and it was deleted as it made little to no sense on its own without the original comment.

Comments are transitory and should not be counted upon to remain indefinitely.