# Why was my comment removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I asked [Why is Chrome using 1.5 CPU cores even though I just started my computer and only opened Chrome (didn't go on any website yet)?](https://superuser.com/q/1666969/116475), and an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1666970/116475) suggested:

1. The task manager of Chrome tells you exactly why.
2. At Chrome launch, all plugins are loaded, and thus the CPU power for the browser process is high.

Since my question had already addressed these two points, I've left the [the following comments](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl?noredirect=1#comment2555248_1666969):

> 1. Thanks, I've shown the task manager of Chrome (sorted by CPU use) in the question and only "Browser" is using the CPU. – [Franck Dernoncourt](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/users/116475/franck-dernoncourt) [50 mins ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl?noredirect=1#comment2555237_1666970)
> 2. Chrome is continuously using 1.5 CPU cores, even after I waited >10 minutes. – [Franck Dernoncourt](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/users/116475/franck-dernoncourt) [49 mins ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl?noredirect=1#comment2555239_1666970)

To which the answerer replied with with useful information:

> 3. Then one of your plugins is causing issues with the browser. Try disabling your plugins and see when the problem goes away. – [LPChip](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip) [48 mins ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801194847/https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl?noredirect=1#comment2555241_1666970)

But just ~one hour after the comments were posted, all 3 comments were removed. Why?

My 2 comments explain why the answer doesn't answer my question, which can trigger other people to give other solutions, and the 3rd comment gives some interesting information.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why did my comment get removed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12277/why-did-my-comment-get-removed)

Comment: **You should have edited your question instead of replying to temporary commentary.**  As for the reason the commentary was deleted, it was flagged, as unnecessary by at least one person. I am not suggesting you “reply” to the answer, I am suggesting you seamlessly address the fact the answer doesn’t answer your question. If the answer needs to be updated, provide that feedback, and it will be edited by the author.  Temporary commentary isn't helpful

Comment: @Ramhound my question had already addressed the points raised in my comments. The answer had missed them.

Comment: @n8te no,  my comments are not obsolete.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Your comments contained information that should have been contained in your question.  So while not obsolete they certainly were unnecessary.

Comment: @Ramhound my question had already addressed the points raised in my comments. The answer had missed them, that's why I left the comments

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I don't understand the your question here then I suppose.  In reading the commentary you submitted, they don't seem to be valuable, once they have been read by the author of the answer.  Since your question contains the information contained within the comment they were flagged and properly deleted.  The commentary you submitted does not indicate the answer DOES NOT answer your question (although I strongly disagree that's the case).

Comment: @Ramhound "they don't seem to be valuable, once they have been read by the author of the answer. " -> you forgot all the other readers of the answer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's up to the discretion of the moderator to delete the comment content whether flagged or not based on their interpretation at the time with all the content on the post then. You might consider adding an edit to the answer post with the detail regarding "*if you wait 10 minutes or more and still see the CPU consumption higher than normal, you could have a Chrome plugin causing the issue*" or you could add a self-answer with the applicable detail if the answerer or others reject don't your edit. Just quick thoughts but it's up to the mod's discretion what comments to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll copy here the answers I received in the comment sections, since comments get removed easily on this website:

> - You should have edited your question instead of replying to temporary commentary. As for the reason the commentary was deleted, it was flagged, as unnecessary by at least one person. I am not suggesting you “reply” to the answer, I am suggesting you seamlessly address the fact the answer doesn’t answer your question. If the answer needs to be updated, provide that feedback, and it will be edited by the author. Temporary commentary isn't helpful – [Ramhound](https://meta.superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [Aug 2 at 12:23](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14512/why-was-my-comment-removed#comment42457_14512)

I disagree since my question had already addressed the points raised in my comments. The answer had missed them, that's why I left the comments. However,  I'm assuming Ramhound's comment gave the reason why my comment was  removed.